# Java/Android project documentation generation

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

I've got a rather large android project and I faced a need to create and manage some project description and documentation.
The areas that I want to describe is the big modules, logical parts of the project. Each module contains of a set of classes (lets say 10-20) which are not necessary are located in the same package.
Each module, in my idea, should have some text description of its core idea, use patterns and behaviour, plus the description of the classes, that are linked to that module.
I want to have a separate file with each module's description, and to link the classes, that are parts of a module to this module, fetch their description, create uml diagram and construct an html document, that is then uploaded to a server.
All this system should be integrated with git, the user should be able to check each branch's documentation.

Could you suggest some tools that are useful in achieving these goals?

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at Jenkins(http://jenkins-ci.org/) and the various plugin it supports. You can easily create Javadoc and UML diagram through its plugins as well as update them later on easily by using the same tools again.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm already using another continuous integration system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really good tool for this is the doxygen library. Here is the web-site: http://www.doxygen.nl/